# CNAME set up on jekyll - CSS won't load?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jekyll

I set up a CNAME a jekyll site I'm working on.

My config.yml has the following:

```
baseurl: "/seenit"
url: "dev.seenit.studio/"
```

And the css file I'm trying to load looks like this in the `head.html` include:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/css/main.css" />
```

I know if I change my baseurl to `baseurl: "/"` everything will load correctly on the CNAME, however I then have the same problem locally when I go to `127.0.0.1:4000/seenit/`.

Does anyone know a solution where I can get the asset files to load correctly both locally and for the CNAME?

Answer (score 1):

`baseurl: “”`
Baseurl is the sub-path of the site. `URL` is what the address will be parsed as when you `jekyll build`. Also be wary of using a trailing slash in your config and also starting with a slash after `{site.baseurl}` or you’ll end up with double slashes.

Answer (score 0):

I font a solution for anyone that's interested.

I changed the _config.yml to:

`# SITE CONFIGURATION
baseurl: "/"`

I then added a _debug.yml file in the root which looks like this:

`# SITE CONFIGURATION FOR LOCAL WORK`
`# RUN jekyll serve --config _config.yml,_debug.yml
name: Seenit [DEBUG MODE]
debug: true
url: "http://127.0.0.1:4000"
baseurl: "/seenit"`

For any local work, I now run `jekyll serve --config _config.yml,_debug.yml`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two configuration files:

The `url: "http://127.0.0.1:4000"` will be automatically set up when you run a localserver, no matter what `url` key has, so it should contain your real website's url.

If you set up `baseurl: "/seenit"` then running the server locally, will serve it at `127.0.0.1:4000/seenit`.

So your final `_config.yml` should look like:

```
name: Seenit
url: "http://example.com"
baseurl: "/seenit"
```

That will work on both situations.

Comment: But **baseurl** is taken into account in both situations, resulting in a 404 when the site is live.

Comment: @DavidJacquel yes, I didn't take into account needing a baseurl locally but not live, it will probably make sense to remove the baseurl completely then.